# How to handle huge data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have a list of objects(list size is more than 25k). I need to perform different operations on that list.e.g. highlight those words on UI, add, update, delete objects in the list, etc..
I also have to keep a check for duplicates.
What is the best way to handle this huge data for such operations.

Comment: Pagination. Anything else will require way too many DOM nodes.

Comment: Even if I use pagination, to highlight text on UI, I need to traverse complete list

Comment: it's not huge. do the operations on the right time, prevent unnecessary operations , catch nodes or their same properties, do beleive in virtual dom.

Comment: @AkashSuryawanshi that's not really a problem. The point is to keep as little in the DOM as possible. Javascript can handle 25k item without a sweat. The DOM can not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You shouldn't be doing computations on huge data on the client side.
2. Use a Database (SQL or No-SQL) or a caching solution (for eg. redis) and store the pre-processed data (don't know if it will suit your requirement).
3. As @Shadow mentioned, use paginations (Excessive DOM manipulation kills performance)
4. You can use sockets to process small-small chunk of data and send with socket events. You can then manipulate DOM after every small chunk (don't know if it will suit your requirement).
5. [How to handle large array operations in Javascript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328351/how-to-handle-large-array-operations-in-javascript)
6. [What's the most efficient way to manage large datasets with Javascript/jQuery in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694431/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-manage-large-datasets-with-javascript-jquery-in)
7. [How To Process Large Volumes Of Data In JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-large-data-processing/)

Answer (score 0):

You can read similar articles on the web too:
https://www.keycdn.com/blog/javascript-performance/

Go to the http://jsben.ch/ and in browse see other's benchmarks

do use document.CreateElement

and iterate over an array is cheap even for 1M+:

```js
var arr = new Array(1111111).fill().map( (_,n)=>n );
var t0 = performance.now();
for( var l = arr.length - 1; l >= 0; --l ) {
    arr[l]+= 1;
}
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log(t1-t0+" millisec");
```